# Touch Screen Interactive setup

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen, user

Just starting out as a pi developer and I was looking for any advice anyone might have for getting an touchscreen to work with Raspbian? I need to be really restrictive on what a user can do on this touchscreen so any advice on how to begin this will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain more about "really restrictive" ? forbidden multitouch ? part of screen forbidden ?

Comment: What touch device, or more specifically what port do you plan to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this tutorial](http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/).  It talks about setting the pi into kiosk mode to make the user only be able to do what you want them to.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please don't feel that I am picking on you personally, I'm not, it's just that you had a large junk of answers in rapid succession and I want to make sure that they are quality.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep usability of the screen itself in mind.
For a touchscreen you would need to either

- let the OS run in very low resolution if the display is small/mid
  sized

or

- find a different touch method like a touch compatible pencil for
  higher resolution. Otherwise using your fingers could lead to
  accidentally clicking on things you didn't want. Or just make the
  needed buttons really big and keep the other things small like it is.
  There are several methods of making a good experience with a touch
  screen but it can be tricky sometimes. Just wanted to give you my
  advice about this because I had a touchscreen project before where
  the concept was easy at first and it got more complicated because of
  the touchscreen.

For the restrictive part: You could restrict the UI itself or play around with elements overlaying parts that you don't need or don't want to be clicked.

The hardest part would be the keyboard: A virtual keyboard is set up easy. You could still use a physical one but that would make it more complicated.
But here comes the annoying part: A virtual keyboard takes away lots of space.
Which is why I thought about attaching self-made buttons left and right (and maybe left and right at the back of it to not make the device too wide) next to the touchscreen and give them the keyboard mappings that are needed. Also combining several pressed buttons together can "emulate" a physical keyboard too, depending on the amount of buttons.

Creativity can solve a lot of problems here and can make it more fun working with your pi! Have fun and good luck!